# Optimization where feasible region has a hole

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

It is possible to define the complementary of a bounded set as a feasible region in any of the `scipy.optimize` functions?

Detailed example:

Optimizing a function over the simple bounded set like (pseudocode)

```
S = [ x if 0<x[0]<1 and 0<x[1]<1 ]
```

is straight forward: the list of constraints comprises four inequality constraints

```
constraints = [{'type': 'ineq', 'func': lambda x: x[0]},
               {'type': 'ineq', 'func': lambda x: 1 - x[0]},
               {'type': 'ineq', 'func': lambda x: x[1]},
               {'type': 'ineq', 'func': lambda x: 1 - x[1]}]
```

But how would one implement a constraint that restricts x to be in the complement of S? I.e.

```
complement S = [x if x[0]<0 or x[0]>1 or x[1]<0 or x[1]>1]
```

The example uses a square for sake of simplicity, but I would ideally want to restrict my solutions by arbitrary polygons.

Comment: The mapping `xprime = 1/x`, `yprime = 1/y` maps `complement S` (in (x,y) coordinates) to the unit square (in (xprime,yprime) coordinates. So for the case of a plane with a square hole, you could change coordinates and then use `scipy.optimize` to find extrema on a unit square.

Comment: @unutbu this will work only for rectangles in 2D, right? For more complex geometries one would need a piecewise defined transformation or so?

Comment: Yes, by composing this transformation with an affine one, you can handle any 2D plane with a rectangular hole. I don't know the best way to handle polygonal holes in general, however.